# How to write a discrete function which depends on pairity

Tags: functions, function-construction

Consider the following function for example
$$ k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2}) y(n)$$
$$y(n)=\cases{2^{\frac{n}{2}} \text{ even}\\ 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \text{ odd}}$$
How can such function which depend on pairity can be formulated on mathematica.

Comment: $a_n$ as you have defined it is not a function of $n$ because $n$ is an index in a summation that runs from 0 to ∞.

Comment: @Themis, c edit

Comment: The defining equation for $a_n$ *still* has a problem.  The sum produces a number independent of $n$.  Therefore, remove the subscript $n$ on the $a$.

Comment: Could always use `Condition`s: `y[n_?EvenQ] := 2^(n/2)` and `y[n_?OddQ] := 2^((n+1)/2)`.

Answer (score 3):

The code that produces the sum is

```
Sum[Gamma[(n + 1)/2] Piecewise[{{2^(n/2), n/2 ∈ Integers}, 
  {2^((n + 1)/2), True}}], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

But, it is not evaluable in closed form by *Mathematica* because it is a divergent sum.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
y = n \[Function] 2^Quotient[n, 2, -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
z = 2^((# + Mod[#, 2])/2) &;

z /@ Range[15]
```

> {2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16, 32, 32, 64, 64, 128, 128, 256}